# React Redirect with data

Tags: reactjs

How do you redirect to a different Route in React using an onClick event passing in some data into the new Route?

```
onDayClick = (e, day) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedDay: day
    }, () => {
      console.log("SELECTED DAY: ", this.state.selectedDay);
    });

    if (day.toString().length === 1) {
      day = "0" + day;
    }
    let dateClickedOn = this.month() + " " + day + ", " + this.year();
    this.props.onDayClick && this.props.onDayClick(e, day, this.state.today.format("MMMM DD, YYYY"), dateClickedOn);

    // Redirect here with dateClickedOn variable passed to new route
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your are using React Router 4.x `react-router-dom`, You can use [BrowserRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter) with the [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) higher order component to expose prop [history](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history) that can be used to programatically navigate via method `push(path, [state])`.

**Base:**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

<Router>
// your awesome app
</Router>
```

**Component:**

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

// ...

onDayClick = (e, day) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedDay: day
    }, () => {
      console.log("SELECTED DAY: ", this.state.selectedDay);
    });

    if (day.toString().length === 1) {
      day = "0" + day;
    }
    let dateClickedOn = this.month() + " " + day + ", " + this.year();
    this.props.onDayClick && this.props.onDayClick(e, day, this.state.today.format("MMMM DD, YYYY"), dateClickedOn);

    // use history.push() method to redirect
    this.props.history.push('/some-route', { dateClickedOn }); 
}

// ...

export default withRouter(SomeComponent);
```

In the receiving component, you should be able to access this passed state from `props.location.state` such as:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

// ...

render() {
   const { dateClickedOn } = this.props.location.state;
}

// ...

export default withRouter(SomeOtherComponent);
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks! You're amazing!

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you first need to modify your `<Router>` component and add a `history` prop:

```
import createHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory";

export const history = createHistory();

...

<Router history={history}>
...
</Router>
```

After this, you need to import that same `history` object you created where you want to navigate, so in your case:

```
onDayClick = (e, day) => {
    this.setState({
       selectedDay: day
    }, () => {
       console.log("SELECTED DAY: ", this.state.selectedDay);
    });

    if (day.toString().length === 1) {
       day = "0" + day;
    }
    let dateClickedOn = this.month() + " " + day + ", " + this.year();
    this.props.onDayClick && this.props.onDayClick(e, day, this.state.today.format("MMMM DD, YYYY"), dateClickedOn);

    history.push(/* your route */, { date: dateClickedOn });
}
```

If you need more info you can read about it here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/history

Comment: Thank you for the reference!